# How I use the Windows version caption in some 'if' statements in order to determine which Windows updates to check?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, updates

I'm writing a deplorable script designed to basically eradicate any trace of Windows 10 from Windows 7, 8, and 8.1. Pretty much a script version of [this](http://blog.ultimateoutsider.com/2015/08/using-gwx-stopper-to-permanently-remove.html) program. The script is almost finished (I think), but it seems that the logic in some of my `if` statements executes even if the variable isn't true.

Here is the portion in mind, with the line that creates the `$Caption` variable earlier on in the script added to the top for clarity:

```
$Caption = (Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).caption

if ($Caption = 'Windows 8.1 Professional') {
  if (Get-Hotfix -id KB3044374) {
    Wusa /uninstall /kb:3044374 /quiet
    Start-Sleep -s 30
    Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID KB3044374 -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 20
  }
}

if ($Caption = 'Microsoft Windows 7 Professional') {
  if (Get-Hotfix -id KB2952664) {
    wusa /uninstall /kb:2952664 /quiet
    Start-Sleep -s 30
    Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID KB2952664 -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 20
  }
  if (Get-Hotfix -id KB2990214) {
    wusa /uninstall /kb:2990214 /quiet
    Start-Sleep -s 30
    Hide-WUUpdate -KBArticleID KB2990214 -Force
    Start-Sleep -s 20
  }
}
```

It's not a complete deal breaker, as the code still executes giving simple error messages when the updates intended for another version of Windows aren't found, but I'd like to fix this bug in order to maintain good programming principals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Get-Hotfix` cmdlet does not return a boolean value. It returns an object containing information if it exists on the target system. If, Else operators expect a boolean (logical 1 or 0) input to work correctly.

What you want to do is use the measure (`Measure-Object`) cmdlet like so:

```
$m = get-hotfix -id KB3124200 | measure
if ($m.Count -gt 0) { //execute code if hotfix is present // }
```

This will give you an accurate output to base your If statement on.

**EDIT:** This line:

`If ($Caption = 'Microsoft Windows 7 Professional') {`

should be:

```
If ($Caption -eq 'Microsoft Windows 7 Professional')
```

[This link](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html) contains a good resource for PowerShell comparison operators.

Comment: Actually, the get-hotfix commands work as intended; if the update exists it seems that it equates to a 1, and if not it equates to 0. The problem is that they are all run in the first place, regardless as to whether or not the caption given in the liberating 'if' statement is true. Would the same sort of logic you provided solve my problem with the Windows Caption if statements?

Comment: I just posted an update to my answer. A single '=' is an assignment operator, not comparison. In PowerShell you use -eq.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for the clarification, my script is happy(ier) now.

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help!

Comment: The reason for the observed behavior is that `=` is an assignment operator in PowerShell, not a comparison operator. Since the the string is successfully assigned to the variable `$Caption` the expression evaluates to `$true`.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, I pretty much worked out that I was accidentally assigning the Caption name in every "if" statement instead of comparing as intended, and my theory proved true when after running the unmodified script, my Windows Version Caption would return as "Microsoft Windows 7 Professional" on My Windows 10 machine. Now it all functions as intended.

Comment: Jordan, Would it be better practice to utilize the 'get-hotfix' if statements as you demonstrated, or would it be best to leave it untouched if it's already working as intended?